# VBA code to read/update a SharePoint list

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ms-word, permissions

I create VBA macro-based Word templates. I have a client that would like to keep track of what templates are being used in the business. Just what template was used, at what date and in what region. Nothing specific to actual users.

The templates are deployed to the c-drive of the machines. There is no global network location for all users. I could just keep a track locally as a text file or in the registry but then their IT has to do something to gather that information in. We'd rather avoid having to do that.

I created a test macro and it works fine against my test SharePoint site and list. However, if I try it on my wife's machine (she is not a user in my SharePoint sites) she is prompted to login to SharePoint. I can't expect the users of my client to do that.

Googling seems to confirm that SharePoint content can't be accessed without some sort of login so I have now decided to try having a hard-coded username/password in the code. Not ideal but the code can't be easily seen by the users and my guest account only has access to this one place.

I have created a Guest User and assigned it the SP Site where my List is.

I **can** login as that user on a browser and access the List and add items to it.

My code fails on the Open command with an error stating "Not a valid account name or password"

```
    sSite = "https://<mydomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<my_site_name>/"
    
    sGUID = "{<guid of list I want to read/edit>}"
    
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "WSS;" & _
            "IMEX=0;" & _
            "RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
            "DATABASE=" & sSite & ";" & _
            "LIST=" & sGUID
    
    'IMEX=0 for writing to DB
    'IMEX=1 for reading only
    
    ' Create some new objects.
    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
     
    ' Open the connection.
    With oConnection
        .Open ConnectionString:=sConn, UserID:="<guest username>@<mydomaim>.com", Password:="<password of this user>"
    End With

<code follows here that accesses the list and adds a test entry>
```

The above code works fine for me if I don't try to pass the username/password but it won't work for anybody outside my org hence the need to force a login.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Simon